# Image Comparison in java?

Tags: java, computer-vision

How can I perform image comparison in Java? I need to compare two screenshots for similarity. Also needs to be able to detect if an object is out of place between the two images (an object in image A is at one position and an object in image B is at another position).

Comment: You can probably do that with OpenCV. https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+java

Comment: It might be easier to start here (depending on your experience): https://www.baeldung.com/java-images#imagej

Comment: @JohnnyMopp How can I go about using OpenCV for image comparison?